# Tic-Tac-Toe game made with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner programmer. In a prototype function of the game function, called `game.prototype.restart`, I repeated some lines of code to reset variables I used to keep track of scores that were in its parent function. I'm not really sure right now how I could've made a restart button for my game another way, but it works.

```
    'use strict'

function game () {
  this.player = null;
  this.computer = null;
  this.turns = 0;
  this.playerChoices = [];
  this.computerChoices = [];
  this.squares = document.querySelectorAll('.play');
  this.spotsLeft = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  this.winningCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],[6, 7, 8],[0, 3, 6],[1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],[2, 4, 6], [3,4,5]
  ];

  for(let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++){
    this.squares[i].addEventListener('click', (function() {
      this.playerMove(i);
    }).bind(this));
  }
}

game.prototype.chooseSymbol = function (symbol) {
    this.player = symbol;
    //choose computers symbol
    this.computer = symbol === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';

    document.querySelector('.sign').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}

game.prototype.playerMove = function (i) {
    if(this.squares[i].classList.contains('play')){

        this.squares[i].textContent = this.player;

        this.turns++; console.log(this.turns);

        //remove to prevent overwriting text content on computer move and make player move array
        this.squares[i].classList.remove('play');

        //remove spot player chose to prevent computer from moving here
        let index = this.spotsLeft.indexOf(i);

        this.spotsLeft.splice(index, 1);

        //push to array to compare for win
        this.playerChoices.push(i); 

        this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player');

       if(this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player') === false){
           this.computerMove();
       }

    }
}

//chooses spot randomly
game.prototype.computerMove = function () {
    let random = this.spotsLeft[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.spotsLeft.length)]

    this.squares[random].textContent = this.computer;

    //remove to prevent choosing again
    let index = this.spotsLeft.indexOf(random);

    this.spotsLeft.splice(index, 1);

    this.squares[random].classList.remove('play');

    this.computerChoices.push(random);

    this.checkWin(this.computerChoices, 'Computer');

}

//compare player or computer arrays to check for win or tie
game.prototype.checkWin = function (player, name) {
    console.log(name);

    let win = this.winningCombos.some((ar) => ar.every((c) => player.includes(c)));

    if( win === true){
        document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.querySelector('#tie').textContent =  `${name} wins!`
    } else if (this.turns === 5){
        document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.querySelector('#tie').textContent =   `Tie!`
    }

    return Boolean(win);

}

game.prototype.restart = function () {

    document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    document.querySelector('.sign').style.visibility = 'visible';

    this.player = null;

    this.computer = null;

    this.turns = 0;

    this.playerChoices = [];

    this.computerChoices = [];

    this.spotsLeft = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++){
        this.squares[i].classList.add('play');
        this.squares[i].textContent = ' ';
    }
}


const ticTacToe = new game();

document.querySelector('#playx').addEventListener('click', () => {
    ticTacToe.chooseSymbol('x')
});

document.querySelector('#playo').addEventListener('click', () => {
    ticTacToe.chooseSymbol('o')
});

document.querySelector('#replay').addEventListener('click', () => {
    ticTacToe.restart();
})
```

```js
'use strict'

function game() {
  this.player = null;
  this.computer = null;
  this.turns = 0;
  this.playerChoices = [];
  this.computerChoices = [];
  this.squares = document.querySelectorAll('.play');
  this.spotsLeft = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  this.winningCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 4, 5]
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++) {
    this.squares[i].addEventListener('click', (function() {
      this.playerMove(i);
    }).bind(this));
  }
}

game.prototype.chooseSymbol = function(symbol) {
  this.player = symbol;
  //choose computers symbol
  this.computer = symbol === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';

  document.querySelector('.sign').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}

game.prototype.playerMove = function(i) {
  if (this.squares[i].classList.contains('play')) {

    this.squares[i].textContent = this.player;

    this.turns++;
    console.log(this.turns);

    //remove to prevent overwriting text content on computer move and make player move array
    this.squares[i].classList.remove('play');

    //remove spot player chose to prevent computer from moving here
    let index = this.spotsLeft.indexOf(i);

    this.spotsLeft.splice(index, 1);

    //push to array to compare for win
    this.playerChoices.push(i);

    this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player');

    if (this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player') === false) {
      this.computerMove();
    }

  }
}

//chooses spot randomly
game.prototype.computerMove = function() {
  let random = this.spotsLeft[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.spotsLeft.length)]

  this.squares[random].textContent = this.computer;

  //remove to prevent choosing again
  let index = this.spotsLeft.indexOf(random);

  this.spotsLeft.splice(index, 1);

  this.squares[random].classList.remove('play');

  this.computerChoices.push(random);

  this.checkWin(this.computerChoices, 'Computer');

}

//compare player or computer arrays to check for win or tie
game.prototype.checkWin = function(player, name) {
  console.log(name);

  let win = this.winningCombos.some((ar) => ar.every((c) => player.includes(c)));

  if (win === true) {
    document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.querySelector('#tie').textContent = `${name} wins!`
  } else if (this.turns === 5) {
    document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.querySelector('#tie').textContent = `Tie!`
  }

  return Boolean(win);

}

game.prototype.restart = function() {

  document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'hidden';

  document.querySelector('.sign').style.visibility = 'visible';

  this.player = null;

  this.computer = null;

  this.turns = 0;

  this.playerChoices = [];

  this.computerChoices = [];

  this.spotsLeft = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++) {
    this.squares[i].classList.add('play');
    this.squares[i].textContent = ' ';
  }
}


const ticTacToe = new game();

document.querySelector('#playx').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ticTacToe.chooseSymbol('x')
});

document.querySelector('#playo').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ticTacToe.chooseSymbol('o')
});

document.querySelector('#replay').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ticTacToe.restart();
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(244, 100, 0, 0.1);
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* choose x or o block */

.shade {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 1.250rem 1.875rem;
  height: auto;
  background-color: azure;
  top: 6em;
}


/* tic tac toe Board */

table {
  z-index: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 188.8px;
  height: 188.8px;
  border: 6px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 100px;
}

td {
  border: 6px solid #222;
}

td:first-of-type {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

td:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

td:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3) td {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}


/* replay button */

.result {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.replayBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap
}
```

```html
<!-- choose sign -->
<div class='shade sign'>
  <div class='box'>
    <button id='playx'>X</button>
    <button id='playo'>o</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- win or tie -->
<div class='shade result'>
  <div class='box replayBox'>
    <h3 id='tie'></h3>
    <button id='replay'>Replay?</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- board -->
<table id='board' class='centered'>
  <tr>
    <td id='0' class='play'></td>
    <td id='1' class='play'></td>
    <td id='2' class='play'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='3' class='play'></td>
    <td id='4' class='play'></td>
    <td id='5' class='play'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='6' class='play'></td>
    <td id='7' class='play'></td>
    <td id='8' class='play'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the duplicate code in it's own function (or just keep it in restart) and then call that function from `game()` as well.

```
function game () {
    // set all positions to 0
    this.restart()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Main question

> *I'm not really sure right now how I could've made a restart button for my game another way, but it works*

Like [Kokodoko's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/190853/120114) suggests, the common code can be abstracted. I would abstract the common code to a separate method like `setupInitialState`:

```
game.prototype.setupInitialState = function() {
  this.player = null;
  this.computer = null;
  this.turns = 0;
  this.playerChoices = [];
  this.computerChoices = [];
  this.spotsLeft = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
}
```

Then call that method when starting and restarting the game:

```
function game () {
  this.squares = document.querySelectorAll('.play');
  this.setupInitialState();

  for(let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++){
    this.squares[i].addEventListener('click', (function() {
      this.playerMove(i);
    }).bind(this));
  }
}
```

And similarly in the restart method:

```
game.prototype.restart = function () {

    document.querySelector('.result').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    document.querySelector('.sign').style.visibility = 'visible';
    this.setupInitialState();

    for(let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++){
        this.squares[i].classList.add('play');
        this.squares[i].textContent = ' ';
    }
}
```

## Other Review points

### JS

A lot of the suggestions below come from experience writing Javascript over the past decade, getting feedback from colleagues, and reading various posts online [like this one](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/).

#### Bind methods and create partial functions to simplify callback functions

Instead of adding a click handler with an anonymous function bound to `this` that just calls a method:

> ```
> this.squares[i].addEventListener('click', (function() {
>       this.playerMove(i);
>     }).bind(this));
> ```

make a [partial function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) (still using [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind))

```
this.squares[i].addEventListener('click', this.playerMove.bind(this, i));
```

And similarly for the other click handlers:

> ```
> document.querySelector('#playx').addEventListener('click', () => {
>     ticTacToe.chooseSymbol('x')
> });
> ```

Can be simplified with the same technique:

```
document.querySelector('#playx').addEventListener('click', ticTacToe.chooseSymbol.bind(ticTacToe,'x'));
```

#### Use `getElementsByClassName()` instead of querySelectorAll(), `getElementById()` instead of `querySelector()`

In most browsers it would generally be quicker to fetch the game squares using [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), but that would return a live collection (refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213298/1575353) for an explanation). It doesn't appear that the class `play` is used for styling so it might be simpler to use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to add a click handler to the table (which can be selected using `document.getElementById('board')` - should be quicker than `document.querySelector()` for a non-complex query).

#### Remove excess call to `checkWin()`

The two calls at the end of `playerMove()` to `checkWin()` below could be combined to one:

> ```
> this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player');
>
> if (this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player') !== false) {
>   this.computerMove();
> }
> ```

(or optionally the value from the first call could be stored in a variable (or constant using `const`) to be used in the `if` condition).

### HTML

#### Use a more appropriate id value for `tie`

That element is used to display the outcome message of the game - a more appropriate value for the id attribute might be `message` or `outcome`.

### CSS

#### Remove excess ruleset

There appears to be an excess ruleset:

> ```
> td {
>   border: 6px solid #222;
> }
> ```

That can be removed, since the ruleset above that contains the same border style.

#### `hidden` class

Instead of adding the style `visibility: hidden` to the elements with class `result`, make it a class like `hidden` that can be added and removed in order to hide various elements (e.g. the outcome message).

### Rewrite

Below is how I would simplify your code. Hopefully the explanations above support all the changes, but there may be a few things that you might have to research in order to figure them out.

I also removed the class `play` from the table cells and updated the code to check if that class exists on the table cells - instead, the `spotsLeft` member variable can be used for that discernment. Then there is no need to remove the class and later add it when restarting.

```js
'use strict'

function game() {
  this.board = document.getElementById('board');
  this.squares = this.board.getElementsByTagName('td');
  this.chooser = document.getElementById('chooser');
  this.message = document.getElementById('message');
  this.result = document.getElementById('result');
  this.board.addEventListener('click', clickEvent => this.playerMove(parseInt(clickEvent.target.id, 10)));

  this.setupInitialState();

}
game.prototype.setupInitialState = function() {
  this.player = null;
  this.computer = null;
  this.turns = 0;
  this.playerChoices = [];
  this.computerChoices = [];
  this.spotsLeft = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
}
//could be a constant - using const
game.prototype.winningCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [3, 4, 5]
];
game.prototype.chooseSymbol = function(symbol) {
  this.player = symbol;
  //choose computers symbol
  this.computer = symbol === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
  this.chooser.classList.add('hidden');
}

game.prototype.playerMove = function(i) {
  if (this.spotsLeft.includes(i)) {
    this.squares[i].textContent = this.player;

    this.turns++;

    //remove spot player chose to prevent computer from moving here
    let index = this.spotsLeft.indexOf(i);

    this.spotsLeft.splice(index, 1);

    //push to array to compare for win
    this.playerChoices.push(i);

    if (!this.checkWin(this.playerChoices, 'Player')) {
      this.computerMove();
    }

  }
}

//chooses spot randomly
game.prototype.computerMove = function() {
  let random = this.spotsLeft[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.spotsLeft.length)]

  this.squares[random].textContent = this.computer;

  //remove to prevent choosing again
  let index = this.spotsLeft.indexOf(random);

  this.spotsLeft.splice(index, 1);

  this.squares[random].classList.remove('play');

  this.computerChoices.push(random);

  this.checkWin(this.computerChoices, 'Computer');

}

//compare player or computer arrays to check for win or tie
game.prototype.checkWin = function(player, name) {
  let win = this.winningCombos.some((ar) => ar.every((c) => player.includes(c)));

  if (win) {
    this.result.classList.remove('hidden');
    this.message.textContent = `${name} wins!`;
  } else if (this.turns === 5) {
    this.result.classList.remove('hidden');
    this.message.textContent = 'Tie';
  }

  return win;
}

game.prototype.restart = function() {
  this.result.classList.add('hidden');
  this.chooser.classList.remove('hidden');
  this.setupInitialState();

  for (let i = 0; i < this.squares.length; i++) {
    this.squares[i].textContent = ' ';
  }
}


const ticTacToe = new game();

document.querySelector('#playx').addEventListener('click', ticTacToe.chooseSymbol.bind(ticTacToe, 'x'));

document.querySelector('#playo').addEventListener('click', ticTacToe.chooseSymbol.bind(ticTacToe, 'o'));

document.querySelector('#replay').addEventListener('click', ticTacToe.restart.bind(ticTacToe));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(244, 100, 0, 0.1);
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* choose x or o block */

.shade {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 1.250rem 1.875rem;
  height: auto;
  background-color: azure;
  top: 6em;
}


/* tic tac toe Board */

table {
  z-index: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 188.8px;
  height: 188.8px;
  border: 6px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 100px;
}

td {
  border: 6px solid #222;
}

td:first-of-type {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

td:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

td:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3) td {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}


/* replay button */

.replayBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='shade sign' id="chooser">
  <div class='box'>
    <button id='playx'>X</button>
    <button id='playo'>o</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- win or tie -->
<div class='shade hidden' id="result">
  <div class='box replayBox'>
    <h3 id='message'></h3>
    <button id='replay'>Replay?</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- board -->
<table id='board' class='centered'>
  <tr>
    <td id='0'></td>
    <td id='1'></td>
    <td id='2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='3'></td>
    <td id='4'></td>
    <td id='5'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='6'></td>
    <td id='7'></td>
    <td id='8'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback I really appreciate it!